# Sending binary-safe data over the network in Perl

Tags: perl, unicode, utf-8, network-programming

I'm implementing a network client that sends messages to a server. The messages are streams of bytes, and the protocol requires that I send the length of each stream beforehand.

If the message that I am given (by the code using my module) is a byte string, then the length is given easily enough by `length $string`. But if it's a string of characters, I'll need to massage it to get the raw bytes. What I'm doing now is basically this:

```
my $msg = shift;   # some message from calling code
my $bytes;
if ( utf8::is_utf8( $msg ) ) { 
    $bytes = Encode::encode( 'utf-8', $msg );
} else { 
    $bytes = $msg;
}

my $length = length $bytes;
```

Is this the correct way to handle this? It seems to work so far, but I haven't done any serious testing yet. What potential pitfalls are there with this approach?

Thanks

Comment: Not an answer, but you might be interested by the [pack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) builtin function. (Edit: the [official tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html) is a better reference)

Comment: You can’t use `utf8::is_utf8` for anything reliable.  `utf8::is_utf8("\x{105}")` is true but `utf8::is_utf8("\xE9")` is false. You cannot reliably "guess" whether the code points you get represent undecoded anything this way. You have to know whether you are getting something encoded or decoded.

Comment: You're right, @tchrist, I should probably just mandate that the client code send bytes. That definitely makes my life easier.

Comment: @friedo: If the client code is Perl, they should pass decoded strings; if the client code is alien, they should pass encoded strings.  Probably.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't really be guessing at what your input is.  *Define* your code to accept either byte strings or Unicode character strings, and leave it to the caller to convert the input to the proper format (or provide some way for the caller to specify which kind of strings they're providing).

If you define your code to accept byte strings, then any characters above `\xFF` are an error.

If you define your code to accept Unicode character strings, then you can convert them to bytes with `Encode::encode_utf8()` (and should do so regardless of how they're internally represented by Perl).

In any case, calling `utf8::is_utf8()` is usually a mistake — your program should not care about the internal representation of strings, only about the actual data (a sequence of characters) they contain.  Whether some of those characters (in particular, those in the range `\x80` to `\xFF`) are internally represented by one or two bytes should not matter.

Ps. Reading [`perldoc Encode`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Encode.html) may help to clarify issues with bytes and characters in Perl.

Answer (score 1):

The sender:

```
use Encode qw( encode_utf8 );

sub pack_text {
   my ($text) = @_;
   my $bytes = encode_utf8($text);
   die "Text too long" if length($bytes) > 4294967295;
   return pack('N/a*', $bytes);
}
```

The receiver:

```
use Encode qw( decode_utf8 );

sub read_bytes {
   my ($fh, $to_read) = @_;
   my $buf = '';
   while ($to_read > 0) {
      my $bytes_read = read($fh, $buf, $to_read, length($buf));
      die $! if !defined($bytes_read);
      die "Premature EOF" if !$bytes_read;
      $to_read -= $bytes_read;
   }
   return $buf;
}

sub read_uint32 {
   my ($fh) = @_;
   return unpack('N', read_bytes($fh, 4));
}

sub read_text {
   my ($fh) = @_;
   return decode_utf8(read_bytes($fh, read_uint32($fh)));
}
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer as it's sound, the only thing worth mention is that the loop around read() is superfluous since you are using buffered IO (PerlIO) which will only fail on error or EOF.

Comment: @chansen, I don't think so. Say you ask for 400 bytes, there's 200 bytes in the buffer, and there's an error or EOF is reached getting more. I believe `read` will return the 200 bytes and say no error occurred. The next `read` will report the error or EOF. That is why I looped.

Answer (score 0):

`perldoc -f length` used to say, back in v5.8,

> ... you will get the number of characters, not the number of bytes.
>   To get the length in bytes, use `"do { use bytes; length(EXPR) }"`,
>   see `bytes`.

The modern docs for `length` don't mention `bytes`:

> `length()` normally deals in
>   logical characters, not physical bytes.  For how many bytes a
>   string encoded as UTF-8 would take up, use
>   `"length(Encode::encode_utf8(EXPR))"` (you'll have to "use
>   Encode" first).  See `Encode` and `perlunicode`.

but I don't think that deprecates the `do { use bytes; ... }` solution.

Comment: Yes, it does, actually.  `bytes::length("\xE9")` returns 1, but `length encode("UTF-8", "\xE9")` returns 2.

Comment: @mob bytes.pm has a big deprecation notice in the top of the POD in the current release and recommends dealing with encodings in a more explicit way instead.